# Ограниченное количество нажатий на кнопку

Tags: input, счетчики, javascript, submit

На странице есть кнопка input submit. Как ограничить количество нажатий на нее до 3-х раз?

Comment: Уточните: «до трёх раз» — пока открыта страница (обновили страницу - можно снова три раза жать), в течение сессии или в течение N дней?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
k=4;//кол-во нажатий, указывается на один клик меньше
$('#button').on('click', function(){
    if (k>=0)
        alert('Осталось нажатий : '+k);
        k--;
});
```

Пример смотреть [тут!](http://jsfiddle.net/azgxtr1m/)

Answer (score 1):

Сделать счетчик нажатий и при превышении им значения, равного 3, не воспринимать нажатия или блокировать кнопку. Покажите код, как кнопка работает сейчас.